# Prevent jLabel from losing focus when clicking on a nested jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlabel, jcombobox

I am making an app that will have some 'rectangles' (myLabel) with a text (rectangleName). Whenever I click on that rectangle, a combobox (nameComboBox) is shown to change the name of it.

So this is the declaration of that class.

```
public class myLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener,FocusListener{

//this.panel;
JComboBox nameComboBox;
    String rectangleName;
```

I added some focus stuff to that class as you can see it implements FocusListener.

I want to show the combobox only when the recangle is focused and hide it otherwise. The problem that I have is that when I select a rectangle and it shows the combobox because it's focused, when I click on the combobox, the rectangle loses its focus so it hides the combobox. Any way to prevent this?

Edit:

Replying to @mKorbel, This is my SSCCE

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class MyJLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener,FocusListener{

JComboBox nameComboBox;
JPanel mainPanel;
String name;

public MyJLabel() {

    this.setLocation(10,10);

    this.setBounds(20, 20,200,200);

    this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    setOpaque(true);

    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    setFont(getFont());
    setText(this.name);
    this.nameComboBox= new JComboBox(new String[] { "option1","option2","option3"  });
    this.nameComboBox.setBounds(40,40,100,50);
    this.nameComboBox.setVisible(false);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addFocusListener(this);
}
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("focus gained");
    this.nameComboBox.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("focus lost");
    this.nameComboBox.setVisible(false);

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.requestFocus();
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyJLabel myjl=new MyJLabel();

    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setLayout(null);

    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComboBox otherCombo = new JComboBox(new String[] {  "otherOption1","otherOption2","otherOption3"  });
    otherCombo.setBounds(40,400,100,50);



    fr.add(myjl.nameComboBox);
    fr.add(myjl);
    fr.add(otherCombo);

    fr.setSize(300,500);
    fr.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

You must start clicking on the combo at the bottom and you'll see in the console that the focus is lost. click on the gray rectangle and the focus will be gained. Click on the combo inside the rectangle and the rectangle will lose and gain the focus instantly, so it's impossible to choose an item. I would like to not change the focus of the rectangle while I am interacting with its combobox.

Comment: you can just put in an focuslistener for the combobox?

Comment: AFAIK `JLabel` isn't focusable `JComponent`, only one `JComponent` can hold `Focus`, valid for most of Pogramming languages, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstraded your issue, `short`, `runnable`, `compilable` and only about `JLabel`, `JComboBox` and `Focus recycle`